# Why can't Android load values-sw1536dp (retina) folder?

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm using [Android's multiple screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html): `swxxxdp` in resources and It support `values-sw768dp` very well, But when I bought a retina resolution Android pad: *2048 x 1536*, and added a `values-sw1536dp` folder, the Android can't load that folder after app run, and I tried on a 2048x1536 emulator, it does NOT work either, I tried `sw1000dp` and it works, but not on a higher number. Is it a bug?

Comment: wow what a pad ... just by curiosity, what's the typical heap size of such a beast?

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYzucFBIlAU

Comment: looks awesome! If you are developing apps for it, I'd appreciate if you could tell me the value of the Heap Size (the max memory available for apps) that you can get like this:   ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
  Log.v(TAG, "---->>> MEMORY CLASS: " + Integer.toString(memoryClass)+"MB");    ... With that retina display a bitmap can be like 4Mb and I'm curious to know how it will affect my applications... thanx in advance!

Comment: @rupps V/MainActivity(12686): ---->>> MEMORY CLASS: 192MB

Comment: thanks a lot :))) I'm happy! This is a LOT of memory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I found this is a bug on Android 4.0.3(ICS): On a 2048x1536 9.7 inch pad, the **values-sw768dp-port-xhdpi** can't be loaded, and the **-port-** makes it failed.
2. And I made a mistake: the 2048x1536 on a 9.7 inch pad is sw768dp xhdpi, so I should not use sw1536dp, the sw768dp multiply density 2.0 (xhdpi / mdpi) is exactly 1536px.

So the conclusion is: the sw768dp-port-xhdpi works on Android Jelly beans(4.1 and 4.2).

Answer (score 0):

As the size qualifer  suggest in the document of a small width required

So add your asset or layout file swXXXDp so the smallest  width required will be that XXX.

Comment: I've added the layout file sw1536dp, but it does not work too.

Comment: add a layout file sw900dp so design as the minimum width required will be 900